# Trim space from all controls before submit on aspx page centrally

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, trim

I have a aspx page, I want to restrict the user to submit any space in any column. I know that i can make use of `Trim()` function to remove the spaces.

```
 <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            Name
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            Last Name
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLastName" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            Address
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAddress" class="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am just wondering as i have to implement this in a big project, so i want to handle this trimming process centrally.

Please help

Comment: You say you want to restrict "any space"? This seems unwise. Addresses can definitely have spaces in them, legitimately. And names often can, too. However Trim() will only remove spaces from the beginning and end of the text. That would be a much more reasonable thing to do. Are you really asking about that, rather than removing _any_ space? It's worth clarifying your requirement.

Comment: At some point you will have to create a method that returns a trimmed string and implement that for every TextBox text value. But it largely depend on how and where you store the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, and it worked.

```
public static void TrimTextBoxesRecursive(Control root)
{
    foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            var textbox = control as TextBox;
            textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            TrimTextBoxesRecursive(control);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help anyway!